# Inconsistency in MO votes

Tags: bug, up-votes, votes

Yesterday I sent [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463459/solving-impossible-integrals-with-a-new-trick) to a friend of mine. He told me he upvoted my question. When I go to my notifications, I don't see the vote.

[image]

But when I go to the history of my question, it can be seen that someone upvoted today. **Can someone please explain what happened here?** What I do see is that Fred's answer has one more vote than the previous day.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask a silly question: does your friend have an MO account with a nontrivial amount of reputation?

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is considered a 'nontrivial amount of reputation' here?

Comment: If you look at your [reputation tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/94729/emmanuel-jos%c3%a9-garc%c3%ada?tab=reputation), you can see two events for today: upvote +10, and unupvote -10. Maybe the changes are not shown in the [achievements dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/achievements-dialog/info) simply because they cancel each other out?

Comment: Some posts which seem related: 
[Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219652), 
[Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900),
[Please consider displaying reputation decreases in the Achievements trophy icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350358), etc.

Comment: I mean at least 15 rep.

Comment: Just to clarify why @DavidRoberts is asking about reputation - users below 15 reputation points [actually cannot cast upvotes](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at your [reputation tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/94729/emmanuel-jos%c3%a9-garc%c3%ada?tab=reputation), you can see two events for today: upvote +10, and unupvote -10. In general, [the reputation tab](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current?tab=reputation) and [the reputation breakdown](https://mathoverflow.net/reputation) provide more details than [the achievements dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/achievements-dialog/info).

[image: Screenshot]

These two events cancelled each other out - in total your reputation did not change. As far as I can tell, this is the reason why nothing related to this post was shown in the achievements dropdown.

On Meta Stack Exchange you can find several posts related to this - including some feature requests saying that some users would prefer to see the negative reputation changes, too:

- [Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219652)
- [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900)
- [Please consider displaying reputation decreases in the Achievements trophy icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350358)

Comment: From what I see, it has been 11 hours since the upvote and downvote were given. Is there any way to see the exact time of the upvote and downvote?

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía The same as with many other timestamps here on MO (and on other SE sites) - if you hover over the timestamp, the exact time is shown in the tooltip.